# Qt::QMDISubWindow maintaining aspect ratio while resizing?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4

I have a `QMDIArea` in which I am having Multiple `QMdiSubWindows`. User can freely resize these subwindows any time. I want to maintain aspect ratio of the subwindows during resizing.

I have tried re-implementing `hasHeightForWidth()`, making a custom layout manager and one third party library `libqxt`'s `qxtLetterBoxWidget`. None of these methods which I found on Internet worked for me.

As per my understanding they don't work for "Top Level Widgets" they will only work for widgets inside containers. Right now I am achieving this aspect ratio by reimplementing `resizeEvent()` and calling `resize()` inside it. But even after lot of efforts i am having flickering issue while resizing diagonally in some cases window also moves unexpectedly (though this is because some unexpected moves are getting called from that resize event). But all in all its not looking good for user experience.

So now my question is is there any other mechanism availabe that QT or any other third party library provides for maintaining this lock aspect ratio ?

can I somehow make that `hasHeightforWidth` method work for my `QMdiSubwindows` ?